# How can I access my node API from another machine ? I deployed node in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Here I am attaching my node Js code which i have deployed in aws.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 80

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Now I am trying to access API with my public DNS with same aws server It's running, But It's not working when i tried with my local machine,

I have also allow specific port in my security groups

Please check below images

[Security Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnJOl.png)

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDYgG.png)

note : I am using Windows AMI

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: Doesn't windows have any firewalls by default?

Comment: Actually I am new in AWS , How can I check ? I only know about security groups , is there any addition configuration for windows ?

Comment: Yes it's clear and  done

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by enabled **windows firewall**. You can allow inbound traffic to your windows instance as explained in:

- [Authorize inbound traffic for your Windows instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

> Windows Firewall may also block incoming traffic. If you're having trouble setting up access to your instance, you may have to d**isable Windows Firewall**.